# Required Field(s) missing result

Tags: php, mysql

I'll just keep this question short. What is wrong with my php code, it keeps outputting 0 or Required Field(s) is missing. Here's the code

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['status_id'])) {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $status_id = $_POST['status_id'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE pims_liip_pallet_purchase_order SET status = '$status_id' WHERE id = $id");


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is the post data in my app

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
           int success;
           String status_id = statusID.getText().toString();

           try {
               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status_id", status_id));

               Log.d("request!", "starting");

               //Posting user data to script 
               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    UPDATE_COMMENTS_URL, "POST", params);

               // full json response
               Log.d("Post Update", json.toString());

               // json success element
               success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
               if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Updated!", json.toString());    
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
               }else{
                Log.d("Update Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;

        }
```

Any answers will be very much honored :D Thanks!

Comment: print_r($_POST) and see what are the parameters are you getting from the form. You validation is blocking your submit

Comment: Since you do not get any error message and you see your own error message, then at least one of the two parameters you're expecting (id and status_id) are missing

Comment: "it keeps outputting 0 or Required Field(s) is missing." means your if case fails. Why cant you check or echo the post variables and see if they are missing

Answer (score 1):

Your error says it all. Since you get to the `} else { ... }` bit, it means `isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['status_id'])` is false.

In other words, your form is either:

- not using POST, but GET. In that case add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag. (actually, POST is default behaviour, so if this is the case, you probably have to remove or change `method="GET"` from the form tag)
- and/or your form does not contain input fields with `name="id"` and/or `name="status_id"`

**The updated question adds Android code. Hence this update:**

I doubt that `jsonParser.makeHttpRequest` actually posts a form encoded json string. It more then likely will just POST json data to the webserver. PHP's $_POST will not automatically be filled with this data, since it only handles form encoded data.

You probably need to read this data from stdIn.

Try:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $postData = (array)json_decode($rawPostData);
}
```

And then use $postData where you otherwise would use $_POST

Comment: What if I didn't use any forms on this one. I just needed the result to be successful to be used by my android app when I clicked the button "approved" or "disapproved". Is that possible?

Comment: Then where is the post data coming from? From your android app? How do you send it?

Comment: I have posted my app's post data. That's how I send it. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Just debug the  `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['status_id']`.
Before this line.

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['status_id'])) {
```

you will find answer automatically. Hopefully one of two post variables is not set.
For debug use `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Whenever I put print_r($_POST); The output is Array()

Comment: Correct... that's why you are getting problem.no post value is set. Please check  your form from where you are sending post values.

Comment: The problem is that there is no form: see the updated question. He is posting from an android application. Most likely _POST is empty because he is posting JSON data and not "x-www-form-urlencoded" data, php does not interpret that data natively and hence won't fill _POST.

Comment: @Lewis Please check your code from where you are sending post values.