# Required field missing json/android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I'm using for my android app a php file to communicate with the mySql DB.But could not update it . its showing required fiels are missing , I think My PHP code is not correct .please guide me OR share some easy easy example.
here is my code.

```
  <?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        $con=mysqli_connect($sql_login_host, $sql_login_user, $sql_login_pass, $sql_login_db);
        if(!$con){
            die("Connection Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
        }
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
        } 
    // check for required fields
    //if () 
    if ((isset($_POST['teamid']) && isset($_POST['memberid']) && isset($_POST['macaddress']) && isset($_POST['countryid'])))
    { 
        $teamid = $_POST['teamid'];
        $memberid = $_POST['memberid'];
        $macaddress = $_POST['macaddress'];
        $countryid = $_POST['countryid'];
        /*$teamid = 4;
        $memberid = 1;
        $macaddress = "'878jjh-iiy'";
        $countryid = 7;*/
        $date1 = "'". date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ."'";
        // mysql inserting a new row
        $sql = "INSERT INTO vote(teamid, memberid, macaddress,countryid,votedon) VALUES($teamid, $memberid, $macaddress,$countryid,$date1)";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($sql) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

.java

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            //String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            //String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teamid", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macadddress", "---"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryid", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memberid", "1"));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    /*function get json from url

    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod*/
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            //is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

log

```
 06-12 11:42:09.491: D/Create Response(7500): {"message":"Required field(s) is missing","success":0}
    06-12 11:42:09.501: D/memalloc(7500): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52ee4000 size:5828608 offset:5558272
    06-12 11:42:09.511: D/memalloc(7500): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5296f000 size:5558272 offset:5287936
    06-12 11:42:29.821: D/memalloc(7500): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x54424000 size:14622720 offset:12533760
    06-12 11:42:29.821: D/memalloc(7500): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51e2a000 size:10166272 offset:8077312

new log.
now I am getting following error @Golu  06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:101)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-12 13:40:57.261: E/AndroidRuntime(12080):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: jsonParser code please?

Comment: 1) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538209/required-fields-missing-result

Answer (score 2):

you are sending below field:-

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teamid", "1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macadddress", "---"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countryid", "1"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memberid", "1"));
```

your PHP require below :-

```
if ((isset($_POST['teamid']) && isset($_POST['memberid']) && isset($_POST['macaddress']) && isset($_POST['countryid'])))
```

the error comes because :-

your using this on android `"macadddress"` and using php `"macaddress".`

please use same parameter on php and android.

Comment: line number 101 is  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);