# {“success”:0,“message”:“required field(s) is missing”} when i test in browser

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have test my php file in the web browser. i think my code is correct but i get message :

> {“success”:0,“message”:“required field(s) is missing”}.

I don't know what happen, I've tried create database but still the same

```
<?php
$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();


if (isset($_GET['kat'])) {
    $category = $_GET['kat'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rm WHERE kat = $category and tgl >= (select now())");

if (!empty($result)) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $response["products"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $product = array();
            $product["id"] = $row["id"];
            $product["nama"] = $row["nama"];
            $product["alamat"] = $row["alamat"];
            $product["telp"] = $row["telp"];
            $product["info"] = $row["info"];
            $product["menu"] = $row["menu"];
            $product["logo"] = $row["logo"];
            $product["pic"] = $row["pic"];
            $product["lat"] = $row["lat"];
            $product["lng"] = $row["lng"];

            array_push($response["products"], $product);
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field is oi missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My DB config

```
    <?php


define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASS', "");
define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
define('DB_NAME', "halaltrack");

?>
```

My DB Connect

```
<?php


class DB_CONNECT {
    function __construct() {

        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {

        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error()); 
        return $con;
    }

    function close() {

        mysql_close();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [**How to debug small programs**](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538209/required-fields-missing-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$_GET['kat']` is not set.

If your file is index.php , try running your file in browser like this:

`index.php?kat=xyz` , where xyz = your category id or something.

Also, please be careful about SQL Injection, your code is insecure

Answer (score 0):

I think you have cleared your doubt, one thing you should take care of is that. Never post your credentials. you might host this website and forget to change the username and password which will make it vulnerable

```
define('DB_USER', "root")
define('DB_PASS', "");
```